# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freezes for small intervals

Tags: 18.04, lts, nvidia-geforce, hp-pavilion

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have a problem that, Ubuntu freezes after every **10-15 min** or randomly when I click somewhere. The freeze just lasts **2-3 sec** but occurs frequently, sometimes it gets really annoying.

This had been a problem after recent update as per my observation.

*What's wrong here? What should I do?*

Comment: I'm noticing the same, although it's more often and less severe (about 0.2 seconds every few minutes). It's really annoying, and I have yet to dig into the issue... Hope we find a solution.

Comment: @bosnjak Hope so buddy